# Reshaping numpy array without changing the data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to reshape an array of bitmap images that has a shape of (50,50,90000). How can I modify it so that I can get an array of (90000,50,50)? - I tried array.reshape(90000,50,50), or np.reshape(array, (90000,50,50), order='C' /'F'), but these options changed the order of the data so I couldn't get the images after using these.

Comment: `arr.transpose(2,0,1)`? Please name the example arrays.

Comment: Yep, it worked! The other code in the comment also worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`np.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html), e.g. like so:

```
np.moveaxis(arr, 0, 2)
```

There's also [`np.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) if that suits your needs better.